# Eclipse plugin open document

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, soa, bpmn

I need to write an Eclipse plugin which uses the SOA BPMN modeler (http://www.eclipse.org/bpmn/) to model a diagram in Eclipse's main view (the central one).

My idea is: what if I create a hello.bpmn_diagram file and load it into eclipse? That would make my life easier when the user saves the file (it is already on disk)

Any other idea or suggestion is very appreciated

Comment: Being on your place I would first try looking for Extension points and API of SOA BPMN modeler first.

Comment: Can you please point me out where to find API documentation? I'm looking at the wiki here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/SOA/BPMN_Modeler/Developing_with_the_BPMN_modeler but there are just code snippets and nothing more

Comment: I don't think they have any better documentation. I have no proper RCP environment at my disposal now, but when you download source codes of this plugin, you should be able to see what extension points are  available.

Comment: I think I've downloaded just the modeler (I can doubleclick on any .bpmn_diagram file and it just pop up with the diagram), I'll search for the code anyway. The real point is I don't know what to search for since I do not know what an extension point is. I'll come back here when I have that answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexey Kalmykov gave the right insight: the extension points (useless unfortunately), were in the MF file of the source code